# Texbox to accept year greater than 18 years

Tags: asp.net, datepicker

I am Datepicker calendar for adding dates for birth date,

What I want is now, that the textbox should accept date which is greater than 18 years from today.
Here is my code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBirth" runat="server" Width="75"></asp:TextBox>
```

JQUERY code:-

```
 $(function () {
      $("#txtBirth").datepicker();
  });
```

Comment: For the jQuery side of things, look at this: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it than by my own, See the `maxDate` property.

```
$(function () {
  // Only allow dates greater than 18 years ago to be accepted
  $("#txtBirth").datepicker({maxDate: "-18y"});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in jquery to handle the simple validation, where if the value in the textbox is earlier than 18 years it will show error. As for comparison part, can try look into moment.js, it provide comparison for relative time.